# How to do something every n seconds while doing something else with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, raspberry-pi

I'm doing this on a raspberry pi. I'm very new to python I recently moved from arduino to raspberry for this project.

I want to send temp to db every 5 seconds but I want to update the graph every 1 minute. However, the graph doesn't update it gets stuck in writeLog. I wrote print "loop" after s.run but it doesn't show. Next I wrote print "here" after s.enter() in writeLog and it shows.

Also I couldn't place plotNow inside sched (Error not in main loop). I tried threading but I couldn't get 60sec for the loop.

Here's my current code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

import MySQLdb
import sched, time

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="log")
cur = db.cursor()

cnt = 0    

tempC = []

plt.ion()
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))


def writeLog(sc):
    print "Insert to DB"
    try:
        st = "%.2f" % thermoTempC        
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO history (Datetime, Temp_Degrees, Remarks) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""", (datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), st, 'OK'))
        db.commit()
    except:
        db.rollback()
    s.enter(5,1,writeLog,(sc,))    


def plotNow():
    plt.clf()
    plt.grid(True)        
    plt.title('Current Temp = {:.2f}$^\circ$C'.format(thermoTempC), fontsize=15)   
    plt.ylabel('Temperature(C)')
    plt.xlabel('Time(min)')
    plt.xlim(0,120)
    plt.ylim(0,90)    
    plt.plot(tempC, 'r.-', label='Actual', color='red')
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')   
    plt.show(block=False)


while True:            
    thermoTempC = "32.00"

    tempC.append(thermoTempC)    
    plotNow()
    plt.pause(.1)
    cnt = cnt+1

    if(cnt>120):
        tempC.pop(0)    

    s.enter(5,1,writeLog,(s,))
    s.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the duplicate-ish question I was looking for, so here is my answer.

You can put each of your processes in a thread, using the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html) module.

Let's say you have a `send_temp_db` and a `update_graph` functions, which respectively perform the elementary action of sending the temperature once, and updating the graph once.

You'll need to define two functions that will run continuously:

```
def send_temp_loop():
    while True:
        send_temp_db(...)
        time.sleep(5)   # wait for 5s

def update_graph_loop():
    while True:
        update_graph(...)
        time.sleep(60)  # wait for 60s
```

Then, create one thread for both actions, and run the two threads.

```
thread_temp = threading.Thread(target=send_temp_loop)
thread_graph = threading.Thread(target=update_graph_loop)

thread_temp.start()
thread_graph.start()

thread_temp.join()
```

Don't forget to [join](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) one of your threads.
If you don't, the program will exit right after the two threads start.

Comment: on thread_temp=threading.Thread(send_temp_loop) "assert group is None, group argument must be None for now". Changed it to threading.Thread(target=send_temp_loop). Also changed time.sleep(5000) to time.sleep(5). My only problem now is that it doesn't show the graph

Comment: @IyaSheep Try and add `plt.clear` in your`plotNow` function. I'm not sure as updating a graph is a pain in the neck, but I've done that quite a lot of times and it usually makes the trick.

Comment: You shouldn't use `time.sleep` in a thread that updates a GUI window.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Indeed. That was rather for the concept, but you're entirely right.

Comment: what should i use?

Comment: @IyaSheep I'm not very familiar with this point, but [`FuncAnimation`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib-animation-funcanimation) should help you.